# SOAP and Ionic 2 / Angular 2 working together

Tags: angular, soap, ionic2, soap-client

does anyone know how to retrieve data from na operation in SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 using Ionic and Angular?

For example using this method:

```
 public List<Client> ListClients(Int32 NumberPage, Int32 RecordsPerPage, String Login, String Senha, String Emp)
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap might help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already tried but couldn't get it working.